# HTML/CSS: Webkit browsers cut up italic link

Tags: html, css, hover, hyperlink

**What I have**
I have a normal HTML link, like `<a href="#">Link</a>`. In my stylsheet, I have set that link to `display: inline-block;` because I have to push it around a bit to match the layout.
The `font-style` is set to `italic`.

**The problem**
This leads to the following problem: Because the text is set in italics, the last letter of the linked word exceeds the box around the link. Because of that, Safari & Chrome "cut up" a color change on hover. See that screenshot where I assigned a background color to the link to make it more clear.
[image]
The normal link color is the light one, the blue one is the hover color.

Firefox manages this correctly without cutting anything up.

Setting a padding for the link would probably be the simplest solution, but I feels like a workaround for me. Is there any other solution?

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qD78e/

Comment: Could you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with the example so we can see it in action?

Comment: @Rune Added, see the edit in my post.

Comment: I now see what you mean, but I can't find any way to fix this besides padding.

Comment: Could anyone file a bug to the [WebKit Bug Tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/) or [Chromium Bug Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry) or provide a link to existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always add padding to the italic class, something like:

```
a{
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 100pt;
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

would give you this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZAUf/ - this seems to display the same in all the browsers I tested (opera, safari, chrome, firefox).

You could also take Kamo's suggestion, although I'd modify it slightly and do this:

```
#prob:after{
  content: '\00a0';
  font-size: 18pt;
}
```

giving you: http://jsfiddle.net/AZS6S/, you can then re-use this (obviously by using a class, not an id).

Answer (score 1):

You can add `&nbsp;` to your links: `<a href="#" id="prob">Link&nbsp;</a>` but it's common bug and frustating one.

Answer (score 1):

You can force a redraw using javascript. It still doesn't look completely right because the text is still bigger than the bounding box, which you can see with the background, but if that's not a problem you could use this solution.

See:

http://jsfiddle.net/qD78e/15/

The main thing:

```
var prob = document.getElementById('prob');
prob.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  // force a repaint of the parentNode:
  prob.parentNode.style.color = 'blue';
}, false);
prob.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  // force a repaint of the parentNode:
  prob.parentNode.style.color = 'pink';
}, false);
```

There's probably a better way to force a redraw.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.link{
    background:#999;
    display:inline-block;
}
.link a{
    font-style:italic;
    color:#000;

}
.link a:hover{
    color:#00F;
}
</style>

<div class="link">
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

I have created the above code. Please try with this.